# ubuntu - erro ao tentar atualizar pacotes

Tags: python, ubuntu

Estou tentando atualizar os pacotes e está dando o seguinte erro ao tentar atualizar

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Você pode querer executar 'apt-get -f install' para corrigí-los.
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 python : Pré-Depende: python-minimal (= 2.7.11-1) mas 2.7.12-1~16.04 
está instalado
 python-all : Depende: python (= 2.7.12-1~16.04) mas 2.7.11-1 está 
instalado
 python-all-dev : Depende: python (= 2.7.12-1~16.04) mas 2.7.11-1 está 
instalado
                  Depende: libpython-all-dev (= 2.7.12-1~16.04) mas 
2.7.11-1 está instalado
 python-dev : Depende: python (= 2.7.12-1~16.04) mas 2.7.11-1 está 
instalado
              Depende: libpython-dev (= 2.7.12-1~16.04) mas 2.7.11-1 
está instalado
E: Dependências desencontradas. Tente usar -f.
```

Depois tentei seguir de acordo com a orientação

```
sudo apt-get -f install
 Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
 Construindo árvore de dependências       
 Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
 Corrigindo dependências... Pronto
 The following additional packages will be installed:
   libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib python
 Pacotes sugeridos:
   python-doc python-tk
 Os pacotes a seguir serão atualizados:
   libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib python
 4 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem 
 removidos e 83 não atualizados.
 4 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
 É preciso baixar 0 B/153 kB de arquivos.
 Depois desta operação, 0 B adicionais de espaço em disco serão 
 usados.
 Você quer continuar? [S/n] 
 Configurando python-minimal (2.7.12-1~16.04) ...
 dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-minimal (--configure):
  sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de 
 saída de erro 1
 Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
  python-minimal
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Como corrigir esse problema já que o python é dependência de vários pacotes?

Comment: Parece que falta informações neste log, neste momento estou usando o *Ubuntu 18.04* já tendo instalado as seguintes versões do *Python* ... **2.7, 3.6** ... Você pode encontrar os pacotes do *Python* para as versões do *Ubuntu* aqui [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python&searchon=names)

Comment: Parece que outras pessoas estão tendo o mesmo problema: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bug/1572900